# Matching phone number with letters - regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I create a regular expression in javascript for phone numbers with this format?  I need to validate that the phone number is as follows

```
1800YOUSAVE OR 800YOUSAVE OR 8001234567 OR 18001234567
```

All the above should be ok. I have the following based on another post i saw here on stack overflow but it fails on 1800YOUSAVE or 800YOUSAVE. For all these at least the first 3 should be numbers.

```
var reg1 = /^(?:(?:[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,})|(?:[0-9]{1,}))$/; //less than 10
var reg2 = /^(?:(?:[2-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})|(?:[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2,}))$/; //10 digits
var reg3 = /^(?:(?:[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{10})|(?:[1-9]{11}))$/; //11 digits
var reg4 = /^(?:(?:[0-9]{7}[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})|(?:[0-9]{1,15}))$/; //12 or more
```

Comment: What's the link to the other post?

Comment: Btw, `reg1` matches both `1800YOUSAVE` as well as `800YOUSAVE`. So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I must have something wrong in my evaluations then, i check the length of the string if its less than 10 I apply reg1, if its 10, i test for reg2, etc.. as in the notes. I thought reg3 would work for 1800YOUSAVE. Checks for the 1 then 3 digits, then letters or numbers. I am testing with reg3 because its 11 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you want an optional leading "1" followed by "800" followed by either 7 letters or 7 digits, so the following should suit:

```
  var re = /^1?800[a-z]{7}$|^1?800[0-9]{7}$/i;

  alert(re.test('800yousave'));    // true
  alert(re.test('1800yousave'));   // true
  alert(re.test('1800yousavee'));  // false

  alert(re.test('8001234567'));    // true
  alert(re.test('18001234567'));   // true
  alert(re.test('180012345678'));  // false
```

There are benefits to keeping it simple. You can also do:

```
  var re = /^1?800(?:[a-z]{7}|[0-9]{7})$/i;
```

#### Edit

If you want three digits rather than "800", you can use:

```
  var re = /^1?\d{3}(?:[a-z]{7}|[\d]{7})$/i;
```

Comment: nice, my only problem is that the number could be 1777YOUSAVE or 1315YOUSAVE. But i think i can based on this :).